# Calculating total wage of staff?

Tags: php, mysql

Let say

A staff works from `2016-12-31 23:30 PM` to `2017-01-01 06:30 AM`.

Here, I need to calculate total wage rate of staff from following rule:

```
Rule#  | Date       | StartTime | EndTime | WageRate(HR)    
1      | 2016-12-31 | 07:00     | 23:59   | 25
2      | 2017-01-01 | 00:00     | 06:00   | 40
3      | 2017-01-01 | 06:00     | 11:30   | 30
```

The final result should consider following procedure:

```
On 2016-12-31
23:30 - 23:59  = 29 min of wage
```

This should come from rule #1, since  worked hour lies within 07:00 - 23:59.

Similarly,

```
On 2017-01-01
00:00 - 06:00  = 6 HR wage
```

This should come from rule#2

```
06:00 - 06:30= 30 min wage
```

This should come from rule#3

I tried by increasing start worked hour by one hour but it fails in case of rule#1 and rule#2.

Comment: By any chance Is this homework?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution I am using a helper table called dates which looks like this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select dte from dates where dte between '2016-12-31' and '2017-01-01';
+------------+
| dte        |
+------------+
| 2016-12-31 |
| 2017-01-01 |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

So given

```
drop table if exists WageRate;
create table WageRate (Rule int  , Dte date,  StartTime time, EndTime time, WageRate int);    
insert into wagerate values
(1 ,      '2016-12-31' ,'07:00'     , '23:59'   , 25),
(2 ,      '2017-01-01' ,'00:00'     , '06:00'   , 40),
(3 ,      '2017-01-01' ,'06:00'     , '11:30'   , 30);

drop table if exists EmployeeHours;
create table EmployeeHours (id int, startdatetime datetime, enddatetime datetime);
truncate table employeehours;
insert into EmployeeHours values
(1,'2016-12-31 23:30:00' , '2017-01-01 06:30:00'),
(2,'2016-12-31 23:30:00' , '2017-01-01 06:00:00');
```

This query

```
select s.*,
        timediff(s.newet,s.newst) TimeDifference
from
(
select eh.*,d.dte d_dte,wr.*,
        case when cast(concat(wr.dte,' ',wr.starttime) as datetime) >= eh.startdatetime then 
                cast(concat(wr.dte,' ',wr.starttime) as datetime) 
                else eh.startdatetime
        end as newst,
        case when cast(concat(wr.dte,' ',wr.endtime) as datetime) <= eh.enddatetime then 
                cast(concat(wr.dte,' ',wr.endtime) as datetime) 
                else eh.enddatetime
        end as newet
from    EmployeeHours eh, dates d
join WageRate wr on wr.dte = d.dte
where d.dte between '2016-12-31' and '2017-01-01'
) s
where timediff(s.newet,s.newst) <> 0
```

Returns

```
------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| id   | startdatetime       | enddatetime         | d_dte      | Rule | Dte        | StartTime | EndTime  | WageRate | newst               | newet               | TimeDifference |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|    1 | 2016-12-31 23:30:00 | 2017-01-01 06:30:00 | 2016-12-31 |    1 | 2016-12-31 | 07:00:00  | 23:59:00 |       25 | 2016-12-31 23:30:00 | 2016-12-31 23:59:00 | 00:29:00       |
|    2 | 2016-12-31 23:30:00 | 2017-01-01 06:00:00 | 2016-12-31 |    1 | 2016-12-31 | 07:00:00  | 23:59:00 |       25 | 2016-12-31 23:30:00 | 2016-12-31 23:59:00 | 00:29:00       |
|    1 | 2016-12-31 23:30:00 | 2017-01-01 06:30:00 | 2017-01-01 |    2 | 2017-01-01 | 00:00:00  | 06:00:00 |       40 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 2017-01-01 06:00:00 | 06:00:00       |
|    2 | 2016-12-31 23:30:00 | 2017-01-01 06:00:00 | 2017-01-01 |    2 | 2017-01-01 | 00:00:00  | 06:00:00 |       40 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 2017-01-01 06:00:00 | 06:00:00       |
|    1 | 2016-12-31 23:30:00 | 2017-01-01 06:30:00 | 2017-01-01 |    3 | 2017-01-01 | 06:00:00  | 11:30:00 |       30 | 2017-01-01 06:00:00 | 2017-01-01 06:30:00 | 00:30:00       |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```